# Subversion: what does "Target path does not exist" when merging mean?

Tags: svn, merge

Using subversion 1.5 I have branch B which was branched off of branch A. After doing work in both branches I go to merge changes from A into B (using `svn merge http://path/to/A` in the working directory of B) and get `svn: Target path does not exist`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that there was a change in a file in branch A which Subversion tried to merge into branch B, but the file does not exist in branch B, so it has nowhere to merge the change. For example:

- Create branch B
- Change A/README
- Delete B/README
- Merge A -> B

Now the change in README cannot be applied in branch B, because the file has been removed there.

EDIT: This will result in a **tree conflict** in Subversion 1.6.

Comment: That makes sense. So how can you merge in cases like this?

Comment: Well, subversion skips the files with missing targets. I'm not really sure what happens when you try to merge back, though.

Comment: Using --ignore-ancestry removed the error for me and I was able to merge. I'm not really sure of the consequences though...

Comment: the consequences are that the ancestry will be ignored.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error with svn 1.5.4 even when there were no incompatible changes. Upgrading to 1.5.5 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because my trunk and the branch had a strange history.

Like this:

```
              /---------\
trunk -------+---+       +---\
                  \-----------BOOM!
```

Merging trunk -> branch didn't work.

Merging branch -> trunk worked though.

```
              /---------\
trunk -------+---+       +---+-----
                  \---------/
```

Probably because the trunk had better information about the last ancestor that they shared.

In my case, I wasn't ready to merge back to trunk, but I was able to create a new branch from the trunk and merge my old branch there.

```
              /---------\
trunk -------+---+       +---+-------
                  \           \---+--
                   \-------------/
```