# Subversion will not update to old revision

Tags: svn

I'm trying to update to an old revision, but I'm getting:

```
$ svn update -r126
svn: Target path does not exist
```

A simple update works fine. Also, update to revision 126 works on other computers, just in mine not.

Any idea what can be wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212713/subversion-what-does-target-path-does-not-exist-when-merging-mean

Comment: SVN is case-sensitive with paths, it's worth to check...

Comment: @Maxim Gueivandov: the same command line works for update but does not work when I add "-r126". Also, this is happening just on my computer, others works fine.

Comment: please, consider support [this SVN proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28313/subversion?referrer=8OEiUGWTjE97oPvcBbCDSg2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could mean that you're working in a directory that does not exist in revision 126. Try

```
svn info
```

to find out the server URL for the path you're working in, then you can try either

```
svn ls -r 126 http://the-URL-from-info/your/path
svn ls http://the-URL-from-info/your/path@126
```

to check that the path existed in revision 126. Here `@126` is a [peg revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) - it's instructing SVN to use that path in the filesystem tree from revision 126 as opposed to the current directory as it existed in revision 126.

Chances are this all means that you're actually working on a branch that didn't exist in revision 126. You may need to `svn switch` back to your trunk path where revision 126 works, then update.

Comment: I just realized that I the branch was deleted and recreated. Even if I can see the old versions, I just can update to versions after the new branch creation.

Comment: (I may award the bounty in 21hs)

Comment: Deleted and recreated? In that case, please check http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html – specifying a revision with -r is not the same as using something like `svn up .@126`.

Comment: Great, thanks! Sorry the delete / recreate didn't occur to me - I've done that a lot myself too.