# "Target path does not exist" error when attempting an svn merge

Tags: svn

I'm encountering an error when I try to use `svn merge` in my project. Here's what happens leading up to the problem (I'm having this problem with svnclient version 1.6):

1. I make a dry-run merge of trunk into a branch: `svn merge --dry-run svn://example.com:3690/repo/Backend/trunk`
2. I commit the merge.
3. I make a dry-run merge of a branch into the trunk: `svn merge --dry-run svn://domain.com:3690/repo/Backend/branches/branch`

That's where I encounter the error:

```
svn: Target path '/Backend/branches/branch' does not exist
```

---

**Update:** I said that when I merge the trunk with another branch in my repo, it works fine, but that's not true.
I tried the merge with another branch, and the same error happened.

```
svn merge svn://example.com:3690/repo/Backend/branches/branch2
```

results in the error:

```
svn: Target path 'Backend/tags/backend_r.3.17' does not exist
```

I can't tell why this is happening if the merge is with Backend/branches/branch2.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764584/svn-merge-target-path-does-not-exist help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212713/subversion-what-does-target-path-does-not-exist-when-merging-mean ?

Comment: nop. i check those tickects. the merge command with the revisions don't give me any response, and svn  merge --ignore-ancestry i prefer don't doing it because the ancestry performance

Comment: I had this same issue and this is what fixed it for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5771655/183355

Answer (score 1):

The directory svn://domain.com:3690/repo/Backend/branches/ must exist. You can confirm the presence of this directory with an `svn ls svn://domain.com:3690/repo/Backend/branches/`. If it's not there then you must first create it:

```
svn mkdir svn://domain.com:3690/repo/Backend/branches/
```

Comment: Hi! the directory  of the branch exist. this is my confusion, because with other branches the merge is successful.